# IllegalArgumentException error on storing images in external directory

Tags: android, android-image, android-fileprovider

I want to click a picture and store it in the external storage directory. For that, I am using this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_pic;
ImageView iv_pic;
Context ctx = this;
Bitmap photo, bm;
String photoPath, img_dp;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 23;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_pic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_pic);
    iv_pic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_pic);

    btn_pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

            if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                File photoFile = null;

                try{
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                }

                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(photoFile != null){
                    Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] b = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        img_dp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Log.i("image convert", img_dp);

        iv_pic.setImageBitmap(photo);

    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imgFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp;

    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File img = File.createTempFile(imgFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

    photoPath = img.getAbsolutePath();

    return img;
}
}
```

My paths.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.falcon.apps.imagestoragedemo/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

I have declared a provider in my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

I am getting the following error:

[The error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0AmT.png)

Why am I getting this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a few hours of searching and trying out stuff, I finally solved this problem. Since, I was not specifying a specific path and was just calling `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, there was no need for me to specify a path in the paths.xml file.

The modified **paths.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<external-path name="my_images"/>

</paths>
```

Here, the external-path tag is equivalent to calling `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()/getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems okay except this line:

```
Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
```

Not sure why you have `com.example.android.fileprovider` or if you just copied from some online source.

Check this [Android Documentation for Saving Files](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html). It has the exact code you need.

**Edit**: Link

**Edit2**: Also check your manifest in case [IllegalArgumentException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#getUriForFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) doesn't solve out.

Comment: I copied this from here
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Also, instead of "com.example.android.fileprovider", do I need to give my package name?

Comment: Give a shot changing `com.example.android.fileprovider` to `com.falcon.apps.fileprovider` in both manifest and `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`

Comment: Did that. Gave this error

Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_22112017_161142615705050.jpg